Using custom baudrate on /dev/ttyAMA0
I am in the process of building an RC car, and to do this, I need to receive information from a receiver outputting S.BUS. S.BUS is a protocol that makes use of the UART running at 100000 baud. However, whilst writing some proof of concept software for it in Rust, I've discovered that the Pi seemingly does not support this nonstandard baud rate of 100000. Is there any work around to this? Can I try to bitbang UART? Do I need to buy a separate breakout board, and if so, which one?
